# Mechanism for interconversion of spin isomers of hydrogen

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, hydrogen, spin

What is the mechanism by which the *ortho*- and *para*- spin isomers of hydrogen interconvert?

If such a mechanism exists, does this mean that *ortho*-hydrogen increases in concentration on increasing temperature?

Comment: Related: [Why do spin isomers of hydrogen (ortho and para hydrogen) change their nuclear spin with temperature variance?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/67316/why-do-spin-isomers-of-hydrogen-ortho-and-para-hydrogen-change-their-nuclear-s), [Stability of ortho- and para-hydrogen](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37758/stability-of-ortho-and-para-hydrogen)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first question is:

> What is the mechanism by which spin isomers of hydrogen switch between the ortho and para forms?

There is some explanation in [*ChemPhysChem* **2006,** *7* (3), 551–554](https://doi.org/10.1002/cphc.200500559) (non-paywall version [here](https://userpage.fu-berlin.de/limbach/191.pdf)):

> One can define three situations. In the first, a magnetic conversion occurs without bond elongation or breaking. For example, in solid dihydrogen dipolar magnetic nuclear interactions are responsible for an extremely slow spin conversion.[4] In the presence of unpaired electrons the conversion is accelerated by the magnetic hyperfine interaction.[5] The second situation also involves a magnetic conversion mechanism, but is assisted by an intermediate H–H bond elongation, for example, by binding to a transition metal center. Finally, in the third situation, a H–H bond splitting and re-formation with other hydrogen atoms occurs, which corresponds to a chemical spin conversion.

The second question is:

> If such a mechanism exists, why does ortho-hydrogen not increase in concentration on increasing temperature?

The equilibrium fraction of ortho-hydrogen does increase from 0% at absolute zero to 75% at high temperature.

*para*-Hydrogen is the lowest energy, most stable form, since it is capable of accessing the $J=0$ rotational level (whereas *ortho*-hydrogen cannot). There are three microstates corresponding to *ortho*-hydrogen:

$$|\!\uparrow\uparrow\rangle, |\!\downarrow\downarrow\rangle, |\!\uparrow\downarrow\rangle + |\!\downarrow\uparrow\rangle,$$

but only one microstate for *para*-hydrogen:

$$|\!\uparrow\downarrow\rangle - |\!\downarrow\uparrow\rangle.$$

So, according to the [Boltzmann distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_distribution), the equilibrium fraction of *ortho*-hydrogen goes from 0% at 0 K to 75% at infinite temperature (in practice, a temperature at which the effects of rotational quantisation are not seen).